# Redirect all links form a category to new links on new category

Tags: redirect

hi i just modify a category link from domain.com/test/ to domain.com/demo/
all my post have now the new url domain.com/demo/post-name 
and now i want to redirect all 1000 links from which includes subcategoryes and post..
domain.com/test/post-name to domain.com/demo/post-name
domain.com/test/post-name to domain.com/demo/post-name1
domain.com/test/post-name to domain.com/demo/post-name2
......
domain.com/test/post-name999 to domain.com/demo/post-name999
domain.com/test/post-name1000 to domain.com/demo/post-name1000

is an easy way to make this redirect? or i have to make it one by one?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Apache**

I'd go with an `.htaccess` rule

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) http://www.example.com/demo/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so `http://www.example.com/test/page` would now go to `http://www.example.com/demo/page` and the 301 redirect would make it permanent

make sure you put your rewrite rule *after* these rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

**Using Nginx**

in the server block

```
server {
  . . .
  rewrite ^/test/(.*) http://www.example.com/demo/$1 permanent;
  . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin : [redirection](https://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/). This will allow you to implement 301 redirect with a with a regular expression.

Also refer this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/redirection-plugin-redirect-all-urls-with-a-regular-expression)